# How to select based on the parent's attribute

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select a DOM's `only_child`, `n-th-child`, etc? I know that there are selectors like `some_tag:only-child`, `.some_class:only-child`, `#some_id:only-child`, but that selects based on the tag or attributes (class, id, etc.) of **itself**. What I want is to do selection based on the tag or attribute of the **parent**.

For example, I might want to select the `only-child` **of** `.some_class`, which is the div with id `B` below, not the `only-child` that **is** `.some_class`, which is `A`.

```
<div>
  <div class="some_class" id="A">
    <div id="B">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "attribute of the parent". Can you provide some sample HTML?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. `nth-child` etc. has nothing to do with attributes.

Comment: @BoltClock By attribute, I mean tag, class, id, name, as I wrote inside the parentheses.

Comment: For questions like this it's best to provide HTML and point to the elements you want matched.

Comment: @MaratTanalin They work together with attributes to do selection.

Comment: Attribute in HTML has one exact meaning. Tags are not attributes. For example:
    <p class="test">
here <p> is tag, class="test" is attribute;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for the only child of `.some_class`, you need to separate the class selector and the pseudo-class with a combinator. Parent-child and ancestor-descendant relationships between two different sets of selectors are always indicated with a combinator (the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) and [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#descendant-combinators) respectively).

Given your HTML, you'll want to use the child combinator `>` to limit it to the only element that's directly nested within `.some_class`:

```css
.some_class > :only-child
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are selecting an element then you can use attribute and nth-child selectors on either the parent or the element itself:

```
section div:nth-child(1) { /*
  any div that is a first child under the section
*/ }

.some_class > :nth-child(5) { /*
  any element that is the fifth immediate child of .some_class
*/ }

section[title] > :nth-child(5) { /*
  any element that is the fifth immediate child of a section tag
  where the section tag has a title attribute
*/ }
```

Comment: That's an interesting comment style you have there. I never know where to place the comment markers within a declaration block.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the child of a certain type of element by listing it after the parent type with a child selector (>). For example, you could find the nth child (any type) of an element with some class by using `.someclass > *:nth-child(N)`, which will look in all `.someclass` elements and find any element that is the `nth-child(N)`.

It is important to note that you should use the child selector (>) rather than the descendant selector (simply a blank space) to ensure that it doesn't select the nth child of every child element (and their children, and theirs, etc.).

Note that older versions of IE and some other browsers do not support such selectors.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not ensured that the selected elements are the `n-th-child` of `.someclass`. Anything that is an `n-th-child` and appears within `.someclass` will be selected, even if it is not the n-th-child **of** `.someclass`.

Comment: That is true. Changing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [W3 on attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

E.g.

```
div[lang=nl] span { 
    color: red; 
}
```

This will make all `span` tags inside a `<div lang='nl' />` color red.

I've made [a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tAcdW/) to see it in action.